# F# ProvidedTypes file not found

Tags: android, xamarin, f#

I've just run into a very stubborn problem, whilst trying to create a Xamarin Android project in F#.

After creating a new project and building the solution, I get the following error, which I can't fix:

> FSC: error FS0193: Could not find file
>   'C:\GitHub\my-project\src\My.Project\ProvidedTypes48851334-82dc-45a7-8461-25f90450a9e4.dll

This DLL cannot be found in my project file.

I don't know what is going on here, or how to work around the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a short sample of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: There is literally no code. This comes from Add -> New Project -> Visual F# -> Android -> Blank App (Android)

Comment: I'll try pushing the project to my repo, deleting the local directory and cloning the repo....

Comment: That didn't work.I have no idea why it is looking for this file.

Comment: I think it's just a VS 2017 bug on Windows with that template. I followed your instructions and even tried removing/readding the packages without any luck. However, on VS for mac there are two android app templates Blank Android App, which doesn't let you select F# as an option, and Android App that does and works fine.

Comment: @RobLyndon [Servicing update has been released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.7.2) :)

Comment: Got it. My build is working now. Nice to see those green lights on my TeamCity page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [bug in the F# compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/4860), hopefully fixed soon. I've run into the same thing today. It seems to be an assembly automatically generated by the Xamarin type provider which generates types corresponding to your Android resources.

[As referred to in a separate Xamarin Forms issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/Elmish.XamarinForms/issues/48) (I'm not using Xamarin Forms though, just plain Xamarin for Android), I've found I can build just by installing FSharp.Compiler.Tools (10.0.0.1) from NuGet. I get warnings about incompatible versions of FSharp.Core, but so far I'm just running in the emulator and it seems to work. I figure that'll probably do until the compiler hotfix is released.

---

**ETA:** This is fixed in [Visual Studio 15.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.7.2).